# xrandr - Doesn't Properly Move Monitors

Tags: arch-linux, mouse, xrandr, bspwm

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux running on my desktop machine which has 3 monitors. I have installed `X` with `xf86-video-nouveau` (since I have an Nvidia RTX card) and have chosen `bspwm` to be my window manager.

Following the instructions on the Arch wiki, I have installed `xrandr` to change the relative positions of the monitors to match their physical layout on my desk. Running `xrandr -q` gives me the names of the three monitors (DP-1, HDMI-1, DVI-D-1) and I want them to be aranged so that from left to right the order is DVI-D-1 then DP-1 then HDMI-1. To do this I run:

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --primary --auto --output DVI-D-1 --auto --left-of DP-1
xrandr --output DP-1 --primary --auto --output HDMI-1 --auto --right-of DP-1
```

This indeed reorders the monitors so that I can move my mouse from one to the next as you would expect based on the physical layout of the monitors on my desk, but all of the mouse events are still triggered on the wrong monitor. That is, in order to interact with the mouse in a window that is displayed on DP-1, I have to have my mouse on DVI-D-1. To click on a button on HDMI-1, I have to put my mouse on DP-1. And in order to select a window displayed on DVI-D-1, my mouse must be on HDMI-1.

I've looked through the [Arch wiki's Multihead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multihead) page, which specifies how to move monitors and position them relative to one another. Looking in the man for `xrandr` for `--left-of` or `--right-of` warns not to make cyclical location specifications, but doesn't describe the behavour I'm experiencing. [Online reference materials](https://protesilaos.com/codelog/multihead-bspwm-polybar/) explain how to set `xrandr` with `bspwm` with regards to the `bspwmrc`. I've followed those and structured my `bspwmrc` as recommended on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bspwm) for multiple monitors.

How do I get `xrandr` to properly reorient my monitors and my mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by changing video drivers. Removing `xf86-video-nouveau` driver and replacing it with the proprietary driver `nvidia` and `nvidia-utils` (and using `nvidia-settings` to permute the monitors) behaves as expected.

This is unfortunate, as I would prefer to use free software, but when push comes to shove, this does work.